# Apply a list to a function that outputs a dataframe

Tags: r, list, function, dplyr, tidyverse

My single-argument function outputs a dataframe

```
library(tidyverse) 
myfun <-function(x) {mtcars %>%
                         filter_(x) %>%
                         group_by(cyl) %>%
                         summarise(mean(disp), mean(drat)) %>%
                         mutate(group=x)}
```

When feeding a single-argument into this function, it outputs, as expected, a dataframe:

```
   myfun('mpg>15')

   cyl      mean(disp)   mean(drat)     group
    4       105           4.07          mpg>15
    6       183           3.59          mpg>15
    8       105           3.20          mpg>15
```

How to apply such a function to a list of arguments so that the output is one dataframe combining all the results over the list. For example, I'd like to apply myfun to a list

```
c('mpg>15', 'drat>4.2')
```

and, as the result, to obtain a single dataframe:

```
cyl      mean(disp)   mean(drat)     group
 4       105           4.07          mpg>15
 6       183           3.59          mpg>15
 8       105           3.20          mpg>15
 4       89            4.53          drat>4.2
 8       351           4.22          drat>4.2
```

How to do that (preferably within tidyverse)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stay in `tidyverse`, maybe something like this:

```
c("mpg>15", "am==1") %>% map(myfun) %>% bind_rows
```

But, as @alistaire points out in a comment, you can shorten this by using `map_df`, which returns a data frame:

```
c("mpg>15", "am==1") %>% map_df(myfun)
```

A mixed option, three equivalent ways, using `lapply`:

```
lapply(c("mpg>15", "am==1"), myfun) %>% bind_rows 
c("mpg>15", "am==1") %>% lapply(myfun) %>% bind_rows
bind_rows(lapply(c("mpg>15", "am==1"), myfun))
```

Or, to get a little more perverse about mixing base and tidyverse:

```
c("mpg>15", "am==1") %>% lapply(myfun) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
```

And for base R traditionalists:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c("mpg>15", "am==1"), myfun))
```

Comment: works perfect! thank you! I was missing %>% bind_rows

Comment: Alternatives: `c("mpg>15", "am==1") %>% map_df(myfun)` or `invoke_map_df(myfun, c("mpg>15", "am==1"))`

Comment: Wow so short and elegant, just one pipe @alistaire: c("mpg>15", "am==1") %>% map_df(myfun)